# Python find difference between file paths

Tags: python, file, path, filepath, difference

I have a bunch of file paths, such as:

```
path1 = "./base/folder1/subfolder"
path2 = "./base/folder2/"
```

I am trying to write a function that can give me the relative difference between the paths. Using the paths above:

```
>>> get_path_difference(path1, path2)
"../../folder2"
>>> get_path_difference(path2, path1)
"../folder1/subfolder"
```

I've had a look through the `os.path` module, since it seems like this should be a common thing, but either I don't know the terminology or it isn't there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`os.path.relpath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath):

```
>>> path1 = "./base/folder1/subfolder"
>>> path2 = "./base/folder2/"
>>> import os
>>> os.path.relpath(path1, path2)
'../folder1/subfolder'
>>> os.path.relpath(path2, path1)
'../../folder2'
```

Comment: So it is there. Thanks

Comment: (For some reason you can't mark an answer as accepted until five minutes after posting. So I went and forgot about it.)

Answer (score 3):

You want `os.path.relpath`:

```
>>> import os
>>>
>>> path1 = "./base/folder1/subfolder"
>>> path2 = "./base/folder2/"
>>>
>>> os.path.relpath(path1, path2)
'../folder1/subfolder'
>>>
>>> os.path.relpath(path2, path1)
'../../folder2'
>>>
```