# Python — Init class reflectively

Tags: python, python-3.x, reflection, chatbot, python-class

I am creating a commands system in Python. I have module `vkcommands` that has a class that processes commands from chat (this is a chat-bot), and inside it, I also have class `VKCommand` with attributes like `name`, `usage`, `min_rank`, etc. Then I have module `vkcmds` with submodules that implement these commands:

```
...
vkcommands.py
vkcmds
    |- __init__.py  # empty
    |- add_group.py
    |- another_cmd.py
    |- ...
```

Implementations of commands (e.g. `add_group`) look like this:

```py
import ranks
import vkcommands
from vkcommands import VKCommand


class AddGroup(VKCommand):
    def __init__(self, kristy):
        VKCommand.__init__(self, kristy,
                           label='create',
                           # ... (other attributes)
                           min_rank=ranks.Rank.USER)

    def execute(self, chat, peer, sender, args=None, attachments=None):
        # implementation (called from vkcommands.py)
```

When a user sends a message in the chat, the command manager analyzes it and looks through the registered `commands` list to see if this is an ordinary message or a bot command. Currently I register all commands in the `commands` list manually like this:

```py
class VKCommandsManager:
    def __init__(self, kristy):
        from vkcmds import (
            add_group,
            next_class
        )

        self.kristy = kristy
        self.commands = (
            add_group.AddGroup(kristy),
            next_class.NextClass(kristy)
        )
```

**Now I would like all commands to be registered automatically using reflections instead.** In Java, I'd iterate over all classes in my commands package, reflectively `getConstructor` of each, call it to retrieve the `VKCommand` object, and add it to the commands list.

**How can I do so in Python?** Again, what I need is to:

1. iterate over all submodules in module (folder) `vkcmds/`;
2. for each submodule, check if there is some class `X` that extends `VKCommand` inside;
3. if (2) is `true`, then call the constructor of that class with one argument (it is **guaranteed** that the constructor for all commands only has one argument of a known type (my bot's main class));
4. add the object (`? extends VKCommand`) constructed in (3) to the `commands` list that I can iterate over later.

Comment: I think you could create a list of all commands in `__init__.py` and go through all of them and construct them.

Comment: The whole question is how do I construct them. I have been able to figure out how to list all submodules of a module, but how do I check them for a specific class, and how do I actually initialize that class?

Comment: you instantiate a class as you'd call a function: `obj = AddGroup(arg1, arg2, ...)`

Comment: I want to do that reflectively. Without typing the name of the class or constructor for each command myself. So that I can just create a new submodule, say, `vkcmds/new_cmd.py`, create a class extending `VKCommand` in it, implement the command, and do nothing else — the command should be registered automatically without having me to write "import new_cmd /// commands.append(NewCmd(...))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this file structure:

```
- Project
   ├─ commands
   |   ├─ base.py
   |   ├─ baz.py
   |   └─ foo_bar.py
   |
   └─ main.py
```

And the following inside the `commands` directory files:

- base.py

  ```
  class VKCommand:
      """ We will inherit from this class if we want to include the class in commands.  """
  ```
- baz.py

  ```
  from commands.base import VKCommand

  class Baz(VKCommand):
      pass


  def baz():
      """ Random function we do not want to retrieve.
  ```
- foo_bar.py

  ```
  from .base import VKCommand


  class Foo(VKCommand):
      """ We only want to retrieve this command.  """
      pass


  class Bar:
      """ We want to ignore this class.  """
      pass


  def fizz():
      """  Random function we do not want to retrieve. """
  ```

We can retrieve the class instances and names directly using the following code:

- main.py

  ```
  """
    Dynamically load all commands located in submodules.
    This file is assumed to be at most 1 level higher than the
    specified folder.
  """

  import pyclbr
  import glob
  import os

  def filter_class(classes):
      inherit_from = 'VKCommand'
      classes = {name: info for name, info in classes.items() if inherit_from in info.super}
      return classes

  # Locate all submodules and classes that it contains without importing it.
  folder = 'commands'  # `vkcmds`.
  submodules = dict()
  absolute_search_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), folder, '*.py')
  for path in glob.glob(absolute_search_path):
      submodule_name = os.path.basename(path)[:-3]
      all_classes = pyclbr.readmodule(f"commands.{submodule_name}")
      command_classes = filter_class(all_classes)
      if command_classes:
          submodules[submodule_name] = command_classes

  # import the class and store an instance of the class into the command list
  class_instances = dict()
  for submodule_name, class_names in submodules.items():
      module = __import__(f"{folder}.{submodule_name}")
      submodule = getattr(module, submodule_name)
      for class_name in class_names:
          class_instance = getattr(submodule, class_name)
          class_instances[class_name] = class_instance

  print(class_instances)
  ```

#### Explanation

The solution is twofold. It first locates all submodules that have a class which inherit from `VKCommand` and are located in the folder 'commands`. This leads to the following output containing the module and the class that have to be imported and instantiated respectively:

```
{'baz': {'Baz': <pyclbr.Class object at 0x000002BF886357F0>}, 'foo_bar': {'Foo': <pyclbr.Class object at 0x000002BF88660668>}}
```

The second part of the code imports the correct module and class name at run time. The variable `class_instance` contains the class name and a reference to the class which can be used to instantiate it. The final output will be:

```
{'Baz': <class 'commands.baz.Baz'>, 'Foo': <class 'commands.foo_bar.Foo'>}
```

#### Important notes:

1. The code only works when importing modules that are 1 dictionary deeper. If you want to use it recursively, you will have to locate the [relative path difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096544/python-find-difference-between-file-paths) and update the `pyclbr.readmodule` and `__import__` with the correct (full) relative import path.
2. Only the modules that contain a class which inherit from `VKCommand` get loaded. All other modules are **not** imported, and have to be imported manually.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you can make an array of all the commands you have in your folder and then go over them and instantiate the objects.

in `__init__.py`

```py
all_commands = [AddGroup, AnotherCmd, ...]
```

instantiate them like this:

```py
objects = [Cmd(arg1, arg2, ...) for Cmd in all_commands]
```

Edit:
you could also retrieve the class names with the method that you said you had of getting all class names in the folder.